# Sorting NSArray, NSComparator block vs. NSSortDescriptor, with null values

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I've been using the block based approach to sort an `NSArray`... However, I'd noticed a sort-related bug so started to investigate.

**Background**: I'm dealing with an `NSArray` of `EKReminder` objects, which have a `creationDate` property. I want to sort the reminders by *descending* `creationDate` (newest reminders, first).

This was my *previous* code:

```
// NSArray* fetchedReminders... contents pulled from reminder calendars...

NSArray* sortedArray = [fetchedReminders sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate* first = [(EKReminder*)a creationDate];
    NSDate* second = [(EKReminder*)b creationDate];
    return [second compare:first];
}];
```

That code, I believe, is correct. However, I ended up with some reminders in the database that had `null` as their creation date. This introduced a bug - the resulting sort was incorrect. The `null` values were neither at the beginning or the end, and it seems that having nulls in the array messed with this comparison approach, as many of the reminders were out of sequence.

#### NSSortDescriptor

So, I tried swapping out the block-based approach in favour of `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`. Here's the current code:

```
// NSArray* fetchedReminders... contents pulled from reminder calendars...

NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray* sortedArray = [fetchedReminders sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

This works.

(With the current data, 101 reminders, 6 of them have `null` creation dates and they're all placed at the end. The other reminders are in the correct sequence).

#### Questions

First, am I doing anything wrong with the `sortedArrayUsingComparator` approach?

If not, is it expected that these different approaches handle `null`s differently?

In any case, does that make the `NSSortDescriptor` approach the preferred method, if you can potentially have `null`s in your data?

Comment: I think you should better explain. None of the "NS" collections (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet, NSTree plus their mutable counterparts) can have any null in any of their entries. Cocoa crashes on the mere attempt to insert nil values or keys into its collections. You may be referring to another issue --- NSNull objects in the array, that should be treated as a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core issue that you're running into here is that you're not manually handling null values in the block you pass to `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`. Depending on which values the block gets called with, `first` can be `nil`, `second` can be `nil`, or both can be `nil`.

Any message sent to `nil` returns the equivalent `0` value (e.g. a method returning a `float`, when sent to `nil` returns `0.0f`, a method returning `int` when sent to `nil` returns `0`, and a method returning an object sent to `nil` returns `nil`). This means that you have the following cases:

- `[<non-nil> compare:<non-nil>]` (returns a valid value)
- `[<non-nil> compare:nil]` (undefined behavior, as per https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:)
- `[nil compare:<non-nil>]` (returns 0; called on `nil`)
- `[nil compare:nil]` (returns 0, called on `nil`)

This means that as the call is being made across the values in the array, some values are being returned that are non-sensical (e.g. `[nil compare:[NSDate date]]` returns `0`, equivalent to `NSOrderedSame`, which is clearly not true), not to mention the results returned by undefined calls.

In effect, these invalid values are being sorted into strange places in your array. If you had some defined behavior for what should happen if either value is `nil`, you'd get consistent behavior.

The following code makes the sorting behavior consistent (and should give you similar behavior to the sort descriptors method above):

```
NSArray* sortedArray = [fetchedReminders sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate* first = [(EKReminder*)a creationDate];
    NSDate* second = [(EKReminder*)b creationDate];
    if (!first && !second) {
        // nils have the same relative ordering
        return NSOrderedSame;
    } else if (!first) {
        // second is not nil; send first toward the end of the array
        return NSOrderedDescending;   
    } else if (!second) {
        // first is not nil; send second toward the end of the array
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        // Neither is nil; this is valid
        return [second compare:first];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It seems obvious now that I wasn't explicitly handling `nil` ;) So, the `NSSortDescriptor` class has (default) comparison logic that does something similar to your code, above? So that it can deal with `nil`...?

Comment: @GavinHope Yep, that's the idea. The sort descriptors are meant to provide this behavior for you in a compact way so you don't have to write it yourself.